# Remove single file from zip archive on Linux

Tags: linux, zip

I have a zip archive (created automatically in a script with `-j -r` flags) and I would like to remove a single file from it. I tried as documented.

```
zip -d "picture_43_9.jpg" gallery.zip
```

but I get this error:

```
zip warning: picture_43_9.jpg not found or empty   
zip error: Nothing to do! (picture_43_9.jpg)
```

Anyway, there *is* such a file inside the archive and it is not empty:

```
unzip -l .../gallery.zip | grep -i 43_9.jpg  
1477092  2013-05-22 14:23   picture_43_9.jpg
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

You have the arguments swapped. Try this:

```
zip -d gallery.zip "picture_43_9.jpg"
```

From the [zip(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) man page:

> **`-d`**
>   **`--delete`**
>   Remove (delete) entries from a zip archive. For example:
>
> `zip  -d  foo  foo/tom/junk  foo/harry/\*  \*.o`
>
> will remove the entry `foo/tom/junk`, all of the files that start with
>   `foo/harry/`, and all of the files that end with `.o` (in any path). Note
>   that shell pathname expansion has been inhibited with backslashes, so
>   that *zip* can see the asterisks, enabling *zip* to match on the contents
>   of the *zip* archive instead of the contents of the current directory.
>   (The backslashes are not used on MSDOS-based platforms.) Can also use
>   quotes to escape the asterisks as in
>
> `zip -d foo foo/tom/junk "foo/harry/*" "*.o"`
>
> Not escaping the asterisks on a system where the shell expands
>   wildcards could result in the asterisks being converted to a list of
>   files in the current directory and that list used to delete entries
>   from the archive.
>
> Under MSDOS, **-d** is case sensitive when it matches
>   names in the *zip* archive. This requires that file names be entered in
>   upper case if they were zipped by PKZIP on an MSDOS system. (We
>   considered making this case insensitive on systems where paths were
>   case insensitive, but it is possible the archive came from a system
>   where case does matter and the archive could include both **`Bar`** and **`bar`**
>   as separate files in the archive.) But see the new option **-ic** to
>   ignore case in the archive.

Comment: You're right, thanks, I got confused by the command line help of zip  `zip [-options] [-b path] [-t mmddyyyy] [-n suffixes] [zipfile list] [-xi list]`

Comment: @AlexFlo: You may have a bad copy of the man page. [The copy cited above](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) says “[*zipfile* [*file …*]]”, which means you can have (a) no filename arguments at all (although I don’t know how that can be valid, other than when you’re asking for help), (b) a *zipfile* (archive file) name only, or (c) a *zipfile* name ***followed by*** one or more ordinary file names. (These can be the names of actual files to be inserted into the archive, or names of archive members to be manipulated.)

Comment: @AlexFlo - You can pass filename arguments via STDIN and pipe to `zip`, as stated in the man page that you cited.  For instance, if you're in a directory containing `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, and `file3.txt`, you can execute `ls -1 | zip -q 'files.zip' -@`, which will create the archive `files.zip` containing the 3 files you piped to `zip` with their filenames intact.

Comment: How much resources does take an action like this? Will the whole zip file extracted in the background, one file removed and then compressed/packaged again?

Comment: @buhtz This operation takes almost no resources, and is time constant (in complexity). Since each file is compressed in Deflate separately, there is no need to extract and recompress other (untouched) files.